# Add Multiple Options in Dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm Trying to add multiple values into dropdown list  dynamically using javascript.

But only the last value is getting display.

```
    function disable_fn() {
        var qualification =document.getElementById('ddl_qualification').value;
        var nw_ddl = document.getElementById('stream');      
        if (qualification == 'MCA' || qualification == 'MBA')
            return nw_ddl.disabled = true;
        else if (qualification == "BE" || qualification == "ME") {
            var opt = document.createElement("option")
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[1]);
            opt.text = "C.S.E";
            opt.value = "C.S.E";
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[2]);
            opt.text = "MECH";
            opt.value = "MECH";
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[3]);
            opt.text = "E.E.E"
            opt.value = "E.E.E";
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[4]);
            opt.text = "E.C.E"
            opt.value = "E.C.E";
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[5]);
            opt.text = "AUTO"
            opt.value = "AUTO";
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[6]);
            opt.text = "AERO"
            opt.value = "AERO";
         }

}
```

From the above code only "AERO" gets display other options does not.
how to add all the values.

Thankyou.

Comment: You don't need the HTML as the markup is being generated with JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only created one element with `var opt = document.createElement("option")` and so all modifications you do to `opt` just affect that one element. If you modified your code to this, it should work:

```
 function disable_fn() {
        var qualification =document.getElementById('ddl_qualification').value;
        var nw_ddl = document.getElementById('stream');      
        if (qualification == 'MCA' || qualification == 'MBA')
            return nw_ddl.disabled = true;
        else if (qualification == "BE" || qualification == "ME") {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[1]);
            opt.text = "C.S.E";
            opt.value = "C.S.E";
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[2]);
            opt.text = "MECH";
            opt.value = "MECH";
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[3]);
            opt.text = "E.E.E"
            opt.value = "E.E.E";
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[4]);
            opt.text = "E.C.E"
            opt.value = "E.C.E";
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[5]);
            opt.text = "AUTO"
            opt.value = "AUTO";
            opt = document.createElement("option");
            nw_ddl.add(opt, nw_ddl[6]);
            opt.text = "AERO"
            opt.value = "AERO";
         }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.add` is overwriting previously added elements hence it's showing only last one.

Instead `add` ,use `appendChild` method of javascript.